# django carousal not working

Tags: django, carousel

I spend two days trying to fixed carousal in my website. Since i am new to django i manage to get a navbar from bootstrap cdn but unable to load carousal in my browser. Please help

Here is my base.html looks like

```
<!--Carousal-slider-->
            <main role= "main">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <!-- Indicators-->

                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    {% for item in slider %}
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="{{ item.id }}" class="{% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}"></li>
                    {% endfor %}

                  </ol>

                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->

                  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    {% for item in slider %}
                    <div class="item{% if forloop.first  %} active {% endif %}">
                      {% if item.slider %}<img src="{{ item.slider_image.url }}" alt="test">{% endif %}
                      <div class="carousel-caption">
                        {% if item.display_title %}<h3>{{ item.display_title }}</h3>{% endif %}
                        {{ item.display_content|safe }}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  <!-- <div class="item">
                      <img src="..." alt="...">
                      <div class="carousel-caption">
                        ...
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    ... -->
                 </div>
                  {%endfor%}

                  <!-- Controls -->


                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>
            </div>
        </main>

    </body>
```

After viewing source code of my website it looks like carousel is not taking my images from folder as i mention. Here what it looks like

```
<!--Carousal-slider-->
            <main role= "main">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <!-- Indicators-->

                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">


                  </ol>

                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->

                  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">


                  <!-- Controls -->


                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>
            </div>
        </main>
```

Comment: Does slider even have elements? Other than that your `carousel-inner` for loop should be before end of  `div`.

Comment: @BojanKogoj  I have corrected my carousel code and it seems works properly but carousel slider is not sliding. it stucks in first image although viewing source in local port contains every images but in red text.

Comment: My new caraousel code looks like